# Is pickle file of python cross-platform?

Tags: python, file-io, pickle

I have created a small python script of mine. I saved the pickle file on Linux and then used it on windows and then again used it back on Linux but now that file is not working on Linux but it is working perfectly on windows. 
Is is so that python is coss-platform but the pickle file is not.
Is there any solution to this one???

Comment: Python pickle possibly prickly. Pickle platform problems potentially preventable. Present possible problem prevention proposal, please.

Answer (score 38, accepted):

Python's pickle is perfectly cross-platform.

This is likely due to EOL (End-Of-Line) differences between Windows and Linux. Make sure to open your pickle files in binary mode both when writing them and when reading them, using open()'s "wb" and "rb" modes respectively.

Note: Passing pickles between different versions of Python can cause trouble, so try to have the same version on both platforms.

Comment: `pickle` is [guaranteed to be "backwards compatible"](http://docs.python.org/2/library/pickle.html#relationship-to-other-python-modules). I assume this means that newer versions will read pickles from older versions, but older versions may not be able to read pickles from newer versions.

Comment: Note that while the pickle *serialization format* is guaranteed to be backwards compatible across Python releases, other things in Python are not. For example, functions and classes may be added or removed and modules may be renamed. Pickle stores references to functions and classes using their name and module, and such references may break between different versions of Python. So it isn't *generally* safe to load pickles saved with a different version of Python.

Answer (score 12):

The `pickle` module [supports several different data formats](http://docs.python.org/library/pickle.html#data-stream-format). If you are specifying a particular pickle format instead of using the default (0), you may be running into cross-platform binary file problems. You can use plain ASCII pickle files by specifying protocol 0.

Answer (score 4):

Maybe you don't open the file in binary mode? See [this stackoverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/283766/pickled-file-wont-load-on-mac-linux)

Answer (score 4):

Pickle should be cross-platform, there are versioning/protocol issues, (see http://docs.python.org/library/pickle.html#data-stream-format) but in general if you're using the same release of python on your windows and unix boxes, they should be interoperable.

If you're using pickle as a data transport mechanism, you might want to consider less-implementation specific formats for data storage, such as json, xml, csv, yaml, etc.

Answer (score 2):

You could use `json` instead of `pickle`.  If it can save your data, you know it's cross platform.

Comment: Not downvoting, but using json for this situation seems kind of awkward.

Comment: It really depends on what he is saving.  If it's all lists of numbers and strings, JSON is great.  If it's dictionaries and class instances, not so much.

Comment: If you are saving class instances, then just use `pickle`.

Comment: The [docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pickle.html) say: **The pickle module is not secure. Only unpickle data you trust. It is possible to construct malicious pickle data which will execute arbitrary code during unpickling. Never unpickle data that could have come from an untrusted source, or that could have been tampered with.**. [LANGSEC](http://langsec.org/occupy/) not included. Do not use except for internal purposes. At least with JSON you can properly parse and (kinda) check what's in there (though much less than with XML, which is the the gold standard for serious applications)

Answer (score 0):

One interesting idea to try out is [PyON](http://code.google.com/p/pyon/) (Python Object Notation). The current version seems to work at least for simple cases according to my tests. There seems to have been some disagreement on mailing lists whether the project is a good idea, though.