# Error with pickle module. AttributeError: class has no attribute '__new__'

Tags: python, python-2.7, abaqus, python-3.5

I have been used python and Abaqus for a long time. But when i upgraded my python from 2.7 to 3.5.2 some error occures. I try to pickle some object A of my class.

```
    f = open(utilsDir + "aclass.log", 'wb')
    pickle.dump(A,f,protocol=2)
    f.close()
```

and then unpickle it with abaqus' python, which is still 2.7.

```
    filepath = utilsDir + 'aclass.log'
    A1 = pickle.load(file(filepath))
```

All it has worked before updating my python, but now i have an error:

[image]

Comment: Maybe this helps http://stackoverflow.com/a/1850806/58129

Comment: Doesn't really help. It says "Note: Passing pickles between different versions of Python can cause trouble, so try to have the same version on both platforms.". But i need to use different version of python"

Comment: You may consider a different format e.g. json

Answer (score 2):

This is old and the answer will not help the OP, but in case anyone stumbles on this for a code he can modify, this error usually appears when the class pickled in Python 2 is not a new style class, i.e. does not inherit from `object`.