# Passing Data Between Different Versions of Python

Tags: python

Similar to this question:

[Passing data between Python scripts, while separately running](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43861164/passing-data-between-python-scripts-while-separately-running)

But I have two different versions of Python running (2.x and 3.x). We use 2.x in my shop, but are running 3.x on a virtual machine for machine learning libraries that 2.x doesn't support.

Will this solution work for 2.x and 3.x, or is there another method?

Comment: Try it and see if it works?

Comment: Oh I meant try with a trivial script? Maybe you could use [pickle](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pickle.html)? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1849523/is-pickle-file-of-python-cross-platform

Comment: what is the relation between the scripts?
does one call another? to they need interactive communication, or one way?

Answer (score 0):

Well the 2 versions of python are different. At some time it will remain only python 3. Python 3 is upgraded version of python 2 but incompatible because it has new methods and functions calls. Here is an more detailed explanation by Python development team [Porting python code](https://docs.python.org/3/howto/pyporting.html).

Here I even find a book to help you better 
[Python porting book](http://python3porting.com/)