# pickle.load() ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'copy_reg\r'

Tags: python

I have a pickle file which is written by Windows, but I want to read it in macOs.

my code:

```
    with open(file_path, 'rb') as file:
        data = pickle.load(file)
```

then I get:

```
data = pickle.load(file)
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'copy_reg\r'
```

I guess it is because `\r\n` in windows and `\r` in mac, but i have no idea to deal with it

Comment: How did you write the file? Python usually uses universal newlines. Did you by any chance pickle an object whose class is defined in a file which you have written on windows? Does this import `copy_reg`?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is pickle file of python cross-platform?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1849523/is-pickle-file-of-python-cross-platform)

Comment: @aschultz but i do use 'rb' in this pickle file

Comment: @yuhan Hmm. I think that would work for reading a file created in Linux, when you're running a Windows script,. Maybe try newline='\r\n' instead of 'rb'?

Comment: Did you found a solution?